# Get digits from filename, remove padded zeros and store as variable

Tags: bash

I have files in a directory stored as

```
abc123.0000.pdb
abc123.0001.pdb
abc123.0002.pdb
.
.
.
abc123.0456.pdb
```

Note "abc123" is arbitrary and so is the number "0456". I figured that I can get the largest filename using

```
\ls | tail -1
```

But how do I obtain the digits "456" only without the padded zeros and store it as a variable in a bash script?

Comment: `\ls | tail -1 | egrep -o [1-9]+` is pretty close to what I need but how I do I save only the second digit from `egrep`?

Comment: I think I've answered my own question, `\ls | tail -1 | egrep -o [1-9]+ | tail -1` works, but if there's a better way please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` is a good tool for this:

```
ls | awk '
{
  if(match($0, /^.*\.0*([0-9]+)\.pdb$/, a)) {
    if(max <= a[1]) {
      max = a[1]
    }
  }
}END{
  print max
}'
```

Each line of the input (from `ls` in this case) is run through the regex `/^.*\.0*([0-9]+)\.pdb$/` which matches any digits (without leading zeros) directly after a `.` and before a `.pdb` extension. You view an [explanation of the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/AMSRMC/1). If the match is successful, the number is set to `a[1]` and is compared with `max`. At the end, the largest number is printed out, or nothing if no matches were found.

This can also be run in a single line:

```
ls | awk '{if(match($0,/^.*\.0*([0-9]+)\.pdb$/,a)){if(max<=a[1]){max=a[1]}}}END{print max}'
```

This is more robust than your solution of `ls | tail -1 | egrep -o [1-9]+ | tail -1`, which will fail if:

- A file such as `z.txt` is added to the directory.
- The last file has a `0` in the middle or end of the number, such as `abc123.0101.pdb` or `abc123.0010.pdb`.
- The numbers go above `9999`. For example if `abc123.9999.pdb` and `abc123.10000.pdb` exist, `abc123.9999.pdb` may be sorted last by `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
abc123.0000.pdb
regex='^[^.]*.0*([0-9]+).pdb'
for f in ./*; do
    [[ $f =~ $regex ]]
    echo "for file $f: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```